# How to calculate the Integral of a SE(3) Matrix in this PI Controller Formula?

Tags: integration, lie-algebras, control-theory, pi-controller

This formula is the PI Control given in Eqn. 11.6, Pg. 419 of Chapter 11 in book Modern Robotics by Kevin M Lynch and Frank C Park.

**$$ V_b (t) = [ Ad_{X^{-1} X_{desired}}] V_{desired}(t) + K_d X_{error}(t) + K_i \int_0^t X_{error}(t) dt $$**

Vb is the twist ==> Vb = (angular velocity, linear velocity)       ===> (6, 1)  Matrix
X  is the SE(3) representation consisting of (Rotation, Position)   ===> (4 x 4) Matrix
(Xe is the error term)

This book heavily uses Screw Theory, Product of Exponentials and Lie Algebra.

Can anyone tell me how to integrate the integral term ? What is the formula to integrate the SE(3) Matrix    **X<sub>error</sub>(t)**

Comment: You don't have to use any particular integration method. As long as its accurate for your sample rate, it is fine. There are clever Lie group integration methods out there but it isn't required.

Comment: I did not understand. How do we compute this term in code ? I know we pick a Integral Gain Value, Xerror can be calculated but what about the integral ?

Comment: I have assumed you've learned linear control theory (PID at least). The last two terms of the presented control law is just a plain PI control law with error $X_{error}$. Just search how to implement a PI law on the web and there is a whole lot of articles on how to do that correctly; e.g. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Pseudocode).

Comment: I found the implementation method. Thank you for your answer. I obtained the implementation form this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taSlxgvvrBM&list=PLggLP4f-rq038O-uUOUEuDlK2Wov-aLOl&index=35).